# Firebase not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do a Lynda.com tutorial on Angular and Firebase but I am having troubles. I found several pages on this error and still can't figure this out. As pointed out on another page, I tried swapped firebase.database().ref() for 'new Firebase()' but it gives a different error.

Please help. TIA!

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCujdl_kIpR42CEqfgC2HxXFZEQjy-uBkY",
        authDomain: "angulartut-8f382.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://angulartut-8f382.firebaseio.com",
        storageBucket: "angulartut-8f382.appspot.com",
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <script src="js/angularfire.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/registration.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/success.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="cf" ng-include="'views/nav.html'"></nav>
</header>
<div class="page" ng-view>
    <main></main>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
   ...
}]);
```

registration.js:

```
myApp.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope','$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $firebaseAuth){
    // $scope.message = "Welcome to my App!";
    console.log($firebaseAuth);
    var ref = new Firebase('https://angulartut-8f382.firebaseio.com');

    // var ref = firebase.database().ref(); //<--tried this, but get error 'onAuth is not a function'
    var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.message = "Welcome " + $scope.user.email;

    };

    $scope.register = function() {
        auth.$createUser({
            email:$scope.user.email,
            password:$scope.user.password
        }).then(function(regUser) {
            $scope.message = "Welcome " + $scope.user.firstname + "thanks for registering!";
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.message = error.message;
        });

    };
}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried with adding `angularfire.js` https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Comment: So after reviewing https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web, I put config in registration.app and swapped out new Firebase(). I now get the error: 'The $firebaseAuth service accepts a Firebase auth instance (or nothing) instead of a Database reference.' on the auth=$firebaseAuth line.

Comment: agriboz, I made the change with no effect.

Answer (score 4):

I found a google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-angular that led me to this migration page https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md

As you can see, the config is moved and the ref and auth lines are changed as well as auth.$createUser(). Thanks for looking!

Here is the fixed code for registration.js:

```
var config = {apiKey: "AIzaSyCujdl_kIpR42CEqfgC2HxXFZEQjy-uBkY",
            authDomain: "angulartut-8f382.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://angulartut-8f382.firebaseio.com",
            storageBucket: "angulartut-8f382.appspot.com",
          };
firebase.initializeApp(config);

myApp.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope','$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $firebaseAuth){
    // $scope.message = "Welcome to my App!";


    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    // console.dir(ref);
    auth = $firebaseAuth(firebase.auth());

    $scope.login = function() {
        $scope.message = "Welcome " + $scope.user.email;

    };

    $scope.register = function() {

        auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword($scope.user.email, $scope.user.password)
        .then(function(regUser) {
            $scope.message = "Welcome " + $scope.user.firstname + ", thanks for registering!";
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.message = error.message;
        });

    };
}]);
```

Comment: I was not being able to signup and after wandering for two hours, found your ans. This ans Helped me.